# PHP login got Too Many Redirect Loop error

Tags: php, loops, redirect, authentication

Please help me. I got this error everytime I tried to login. - "This webpage has a redirect loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"
Please help me and I'll appreciate your help very much. thanks.

This is my index.php

```
<?php
include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script
?>
```

This is my login.php

```
<?php

session_start();
$error = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
    } else {
        // Define $username and $password
        $usernameLogin = $_POST['email'];
        $passwordLogin = $_POST['password'];
        // Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
        $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "apple", "Apple318992");
        // To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
        $username = stripslashes($usernameLogin);
        $password = stripslashes($passwordLogin);
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
        // Selecting Database
        $db = mysql_select_db("TS", $connection);
        // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
        $query = mysql_query("select * from Users where password='$password' AND email='$usernameLogin'", $connection);
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($rows == 1) {
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $usernameLogin; // Initializing Session
        } else {
            $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
        }
    }
}



if (isset($_SESSION["login_user"])) {
    header("Location:timesheets.php");
}
?>
```

This is my session.php

```
<?php

include ('DBConnect.php');
session_start(); // Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql = mysql_query("select email from Users where email='$user_check'", $conn);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session = $row['email'];
if (!isset($login_session)) {
    mysql_close($conn); // Closing Connection
    header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

Comment: What is `timesheets.php`?

Comment: U are not destroying your session?

Comment: That is the home page.

Comment: Hi can you please show me how to fix the problem? thanks a lot. @Rens Tillmann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your session.php you have to destroy the session because it might be set still but without that the query can find a existing user?

To unset sessions do this:

`unset();` for all the session variables `unset($_SESSION['login_user']);` for a specific session

Please put that before redirecting to index.php.

Otherwise I don't know how to help you sorry.

Also do you have php error / debug enabled? Normally session_start(); should be at very first line in your php file if I am correct, or it throws error.

Comment: Hi. thank you very much for this.!! Really appreciate it. I don't have the error anymore but login is still unsuccessful, I mean it just stays on index.php page. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Ok good, then use `var_dump($_SESSION['login_user']);` to see if it contains the right values, and check if database could find a row with this value. But I bet you will be able to fix that issue on your own :)

Comment: Hi. Now I am okay already. Again, Thanks a lot for help !! :D

Comment: Yay! Glad it helped you out!

Answer (score 3):

instead of : **header('Location: index.php');**

try to do it with javascript :

**echo '< script> document.location.href="index.php"< /script>';**